# Parcel a bundle with plain types gives RuntimeException Unmarshalling unknown type code

Tags: android, parcel

I want to parcel a Bundle from onSaveInstanceState method for storing it temporarily.

```
@Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            savedInstanceState.putBoolean(..);
            savedInstanceState.putInt(..);
//...
           super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
           userInputs = savedInstanceState;
    }
```

I only use putBoolean and putInt.
Somewhere else I save this data:

```
Parcel p1 = Parcel.obtain();
p1.writeBundle(userInputs);
byte[] b1 = p1.marshall();
```

and reuse it later:

```
Parcel p11 = Parcel.obtain();
p11.unmarshall(b1, 0, b1.length);
p11.setDataPosition(0);

Object o = p11.readValue(Bundle.class.getClassLoader());
Bundle result2 = (Bundle) o;
```

I get this Exception @p11.readValue

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@41e42c70: Unmarshalling unknown type code 4292 at offset 0
```

I dont know, what is the problem.

Comment: Any particular reason you're not calling `p11.readBundle()` in an attempt to deserialize the bundle?

Comment: If so I get an empty Bundle from this function.